# ReactDOM.render cause Chrome debug React stuck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I'm trying WebStorm and VSCode to debug React, both of them have this issue.

I'm using the following simple React code and the Chrome debug is stuck.

**How to reproduce:**

- See my video ([attached file in this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-47656#focus=Comments-27-4423056.0-0))
- Set breakpoint in `ReactDOM.render`
- Hit <kbd>F4</kbd> debug html with idea built-in webserver
- Click WebStorm debug toolwindow -> reload in browser
- Debug stuck and WebStorm debug toolwindow -> "restart" cannot restart debug (also the Chrome debug tab is stuck cannot reload)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
  class App extends React.Component {
  }

  const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
  ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), domContainer);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also report this in [React GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19952), it's very severe issue cause I hard to dev react.

Answer (score 0):

update:

following add "beforeunload" is trouble, it need add "beforeunload" code in project

the better way is make webstorm or vs plugin, use "chrome devtools protocol", before refresh run js "ReactDOM = null"

update:

in short, the solution is add following

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
            ReactDOM = null
        });
```

This bug still exist in latest chrome, here is [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1134899&q=ReactDOM.render%20cause%20Chrome%20debug%20React%20stuck&can=2)

I find tmp solution

before refresh, in runtime run js "ReactDOM = null" and then refresh will not stuck

so here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
        ReactDOM = null
    });

ReactDOM.render(app, domContainer);
```

the stuck reason is:

react code:

```
  function unbatchedUpdates(fn, a) {
    var prevExecutionContext = executionContext;
    executionContext &= ~BatchedContext;
    executionContext |= LegacyUnbatchedContext;

    try {
      return fn(a);
    } finally {
      executionContext = prevExecutionContext;

      if (executionContext === NoContext) {
        // Flush the immediate callbacks that were scheduled during this batch
        flushSyncCallbackQueue();
      }
    }
  }
```

**flushSyncCallbackQueue** cause this bug

old:
I give answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196588/6011193)

in short, use chrome extension api "end process" current tab process and then reload, it means make force reload even when debug stuck