# chrome devtools debug react, hit "refresh" cause debug stuck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I don't use any remote debug(webstorm and devtools)

just use chrome devtools

when debug stop in breakpoint in devtools

hit "ctrl+r" refresh also stuck(tab blank, debug session cannot restart)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<script src="../node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
  var e = React.createElement

  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return e("div")
    }
  }

  const domContainer = document.querySelector('#root');
  ReactDOM.render(e(App), domContainer);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably a bug in devtools. I usually press F8 first (to unpause), then Ctrl-R or F5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

here is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196599/6011193

update:
I report this bug to chrome team, please help me vote this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1134899#c_ts1603534836

old:
I guess this chrome bug, so here is my tmp solution

**in short, use chrome extension api "end process" current tab process and then reload**, it's same manually chrome > task manager > end process and then hit reload

in detail:

use [chrome.processes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes), it require latest **[chrome dev channel](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)(not chrome stable version)**

`chrome.processes.terminate` to terminate current tab process

`chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listen "ctrl+r" reload event, when reload "localhost" dev url, first "end process" and then reload

following is my part solution code(full code is very long so I omit it, but you can refer to make yourself code)

```
/**
 *
 */
import {CrxAsync} from "./node_modules/ro-crx/src/index.js"

class ForceReloadInLocalhost extends CrxAsync {
  constructor() {
    super()

    chrome.processes.onExited.addListener(() => {
      this.startReload()
    })
  }

  start(tab) {
    if (tab == null) {
      this.getCurTab((curTab) => {
        this.start(curTab)
      })
    } else {
      this.tabId = tab.id;
      var tabId = this.tabId
      if (tab.url.match(/localhost/)) {
        this.killProcess(tabId, (status) => {
          if (status == "not_process") {
            this.startReload()
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.startReload()
      }
    }
  }

  startReload() {
    if (this.tabId) {
      this.reload(this.tabId, {}, () => {
        this.tabId = null
      })
    }
  }
}

var forceReload = new ForceReloadInLocalhost()

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((cmd) => {
  if (cmd == "forceReload") {
    forceReload.start()
  }
})

var isForceReload = true
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (tab.url.match(/^https?:\/\/localhost/)) {
    if (changeInfo.url == undefined /* it means is reload, so url doesn't change*/ && changeInfo.status == "loading") {
      if (!isForceReload) {
        isForceReload = true
        forceReload.start(tab);
      } else {
        isForceReload = false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this workaround](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22369500/chrome-dev-tools-stuck-unresponsive-on-application-tab?hl=en) for a similar issue:

1. Try to open devtools in incognito mode
2. choose another tab in devtools
3. close incognito window
4. try dev tools on regular one again